# Single Table Inheritance with model subdirectories in Rails 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, single-table-inheritance, rails-models

I have a model `Sport`. Using single table inheritance I have 2 other models, `Cricket` and `Football` so that

```
class Cricket < Sport and class Football < Sport
```

I put these two models in a subfolder inside models directory called sports. I added the type column to `Sport` and put the value as `Cricket` or `Football`, whatever was appropriate. Also, I was able to create objects using `Cricket.new` or `Football.new`.

This structure works fine till Rails 3.2.6.

But now with Rails 3.2.11, any model file inside a subfolder has to be modularised. So, it looks like this now:

```
module Sports
  class Cricket < Sport
```

Now, rails is not able to load the class `Cricket` or `Football` alone. So, `Cricket.new` or `Football.new` does not work. If I do `Sports::Cricket.new`, then it is a problem for me because the type column has to be the class name, i.e. `Sports::Cricket`.

What should I do in Rails 3.2.11 for single table inheritance to work? I don't want to put values like `Sports::Cricket` in my type column.
Also, I do not want to remove the subdirectory structure.

Answer (score 1):

I just dealt with a similar problem myself. See [How to reload files in app/models/subdirectory in dev environment for STI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711505/how-to-reload-files-in-app-models-subdirectory-in-dev-environment-for-sti/14711506#14711506). Basically you need to `require_dependency` your subclasses on initalization and reload, in the parent class or in config files somewhere. It's a rails lazy load thing, [and it doesn't seem like they want to change it](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8699). I found [Alex Reisner's post](http://www.alexreisner.com/code/single-table-inheritance-in-rails) incredibly helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use this?

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]
```

Comment: Yes, I am already using it. But, this just solves the problem of loading the subfolders. It is not loading my classes because the class has now become Sports::Cricket and not just Cricket, and I am using Cricket.new or Cricket.create